# Como resolver o erro java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException

Tags: android, intent

Galera estou tendo esse erro quando tento compartilhar um bitmap via intent no Android 7.0, já pesquisei bastante e não consegui resolver, pelo que vi o próprio Google tem a recomendação para evitar o erro https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html mas não consegui entender a solução proposta nem encontrei outra alternativa.

Esse aqui é o código de exemplo do Google, não entendi a classe DataFragment o que ela é.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private RetainedFragment dataFragment;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // find the retained fragment on activity restarts
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        dataFragment = (DataFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(“data”);

        // create the fragment and data the first time
        if (dataFragment == null) {
            // add the fragment
            dataFragment = new DataFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(dataFragment, “data”).commit();
            // load the data from the web
            dataFragment.setData(loadMyData());
        }

        // the data is available in dataFragment.getData()
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // store the data in the fragment
        dataFragment.setData(collectMyLoadedData());
    }
}
```

Comment: o que fez? ajudaria se mostrasse o código...

Comment: Coloquei o código de exemplo do Google que estou tendo a dúvida.

Answer (score 4):

**ERRO**

Isso pode ocorrer, quando você passa grande quantidade de dados através de parâmetros de uma `Intent`!

Quando você recebe essa exceção em seu aplicativo, analise  se  você está trocando muitos dados entre seus serviços!

Usando `Intent` para compartilhar dados enormes, (por exemplo, o usuário seleciona um número enorme de arquivos  de compartilhamento de galeria, os URIs dos arquivos selecionados serão transferidos usando `Intents`).

No seu caso esteja tentado passar a imagem (`Bitmap`) no `Intent` salve a em algum lugar (alguma pasta do sistema) e compartilhe apenas a `URI`.

Sem seu código, fica difícil ajudar mais!

**CÓDIGO**

O código que você adicionou acima, trata se de uma solução de que ao invés de setar os parâmetros via `Bundle`

EXEMPLO:

```
    FragmentManager dataFragment = new FragmentManager();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable("dataObject", loadMyData());   //parameters are (key, value).
    dataFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    fm.beginTransaction().add(dataFragment, “data”).commit();
```

Você pode adicionar diretamente no via Set:

```
  // load the data from the web
   dataFragment.setData(loadMyData());
```

[Fonte1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39098590/android-os-transactiontoolargeexception-on-nougat)

[Fonte2](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)